# Share private key with expiry period

Tags: drm, secret-sharing, pkcs1

I'd like a way to encrypt my data, and temporarily share access to 'semi-trusted' parties.

If I encrypt my data with my private key, is it possible to share my private key (or some derivative of it) with an expiry time of X hours? Such that another party can use it to decrypt my data until it expires.

BTW - I understand the caveats that once my data is decrypted, if my 'semi-trusted' party turns out to be a bad-actor, that my data is now out in the wild.

Comment: I think this falls into the DRM category and you may want to look at other discussions on it on ths forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bits do not make suicide after some time or degrade in quality. Thus it is not possible to construct a key which enforces the time limit by itself. Instead you would need some protected service or device which can be accessed with the shared key and will provide the real key or the decrypted data. The time restriction then must be enforced by this service.